# Printing the recursive calls for fibonnaci numbers

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

How to print the result of the fibonnaci recursive calls such that the output looks like this

Rec results is
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(0) is: 0
Fib(2) is: 1
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(3) is: 2
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(0) is: 0
Fib(2) is: 1
Fib(4) is: 3
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(0) is: 0
Fib(2) is: 1
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(3) is: 2
Fib(5) is: 5

Here is my code

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Fibonacci fib = new Fibonacci();
      System.out.println("Rec results is ");
      fib.recFib(5);

   }
}

class Fibonacci {
   
     //Your code starts here
      public int recFib(int n){
         
         if(n <= 1) {
            return n;
         }
         else {
            int result = recFib(n -1) + recFib(n-2);
            //System.out.println("Fib("+ n +") is: "+ result);
            return recFib(n -1) + recFib(n-2);
         }
      }
   // your code ends here

}
```

I have tried to put the print statement in different locations but never am able to get the proper output. This is not a homework question but part of a class lesson so hopefully you guys can help me understand it better. I believe you can only use one print statement.

Comment: Don't call the recursion twice! Recursive Fibonacci ias bad enough already without making it twice as slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you extract the `print` statement out of the `if-else`, then the recursive call will happen first and print afterwards (so you will print the results of `n-1` and `n-2` before printing the result of `n`). In that way you obtain the desired result.

```
class Fibonacci {

    //Your code starts here
    public int recFib(int n) {
        int result;
        if (n <= 1) {
            result = n;
        } else {
            result = recFib(n - 1) + recFib(n - 2);
        }
        System.out.println("Fib(" + n + ") is: " + result);
        return result;
    }
    // your code ends here
}
```

This results in

```
Rec results is 
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(0) is: 0
Fib(2) is: 1
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(3) is: 2
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(0) is: 0
Fib(2) is: 1
Fib(4) is: 3
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(0) is: 0
Fib(2) is: 1
Fib(1) is: 1
Fib(3) is: 2
Fib(5) is: 5
```

Good luck with the class!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to reduce `n` until it equals `1` and then print the the desired values in reverse order.  So I reversed your conditional to compute the `nth` fibonacci value.

```
public static int recFib(int n) {
   int result = n;
   if (n > 1) {
       result = recFib(n-1) + recFib(n-2);
   }
   System.out.printf("Fib(%d) is %d%n", n, result);
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Print statement should be out of if-else statement:

```
    public int recFib(int n) {
        int result;
        if (n <= 1) {
            result = n;
        } else {
            result = recFib(n - 1) + recFib(n - 2);
        }
        System.out.printf("Fib(%d) is: %d\n", n, result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a brief explanation on how bringing the System.out.println statement outside the if block actually does the trick